# Lagrange remainder - is t contained within an open or closed interval?

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

[image]

Above is the taylor series centred at a including the lagrange remainder.
Can t be equal to a or b?

Comment: In Michael Spivak's book: Calculus, it is proved in Chapter 20 Theorem 4 (I'm referring to 3rd edition) that $t$ can be chosen to lie in the open interval $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take $t$ to lie on the open interval $(a,b)$.

Reference: [wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html)